# Rust errors in watchexec crate examples

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I begin in Rust because I need it for a project, I have try watchexec, and nothing to done when I try the watchexec example there is some errors, when I try to correct it with the suggestion, always errors, could someone help me?

```rust
use miette::{IntoDiagnostic, Result};
use watchexec::Watchexec;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let wx = Watchexec::new(|mut action| {
        // you don't HAVE to spawn jobs:
        // here, we just print out the events as they come in
        for event in action.events.iter() {
            eprintln!("{event:?}");
        }

        // quit when we get a signal
        if action.signals().next().is_some() {
            eprintln!("[Quitting...]");
            action.quit();
        }

        action
    })?;

    // start the engine
    let main = wx.expect("REASON").mainf();

    // and watch all files in the current directory:
    wx.unwrap().config.pathset(["."]);

    let _ = main.await.into_diagnostic()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Here is my `cargo compille --all-features` errors:

```
dewachen@monordi:~/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom$ cargo build --all-features
   Compiling w-hdom v0.1.0 (/home/dewachen/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `wcs`
  --> src/main.rs:26:2
   |
6  |     let wcs = Watchexec::new(|mut action| {
   |         --- move occurs because `wcs` has type `Result<Arc<Watchexec>, CriticalError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
23 |     let main = wcs.expect("REASON").mainf();
   |                --- ---------------- `wcs` moved due to this method call
   |                |
   |                help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
...
26 |     wcs.unwrap().config.pathset(["."]);
   |     ^^^ value used here after move
   |
note: `Result::<T, E>::expect` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `wcs`
  --> /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1024:19
help: you could `clone` the value and consume it, if the `CriticalError: Clone` trait bound could be satisfied
   |
23 |     let main = wcs.clone().expect("REASON").mainf();
   |                   ++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `w-hdom` (bin "w-hdom") due to 1 previous error
dewachen@monordi:~/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom$ cargo build --all-features
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
   Compiling w-hdom v0.1.0 (/home/dewachen/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `wx`
  --> src/main.rs:26:2
   |
6  |     let wx = Watchexec::new(|mut action| {
   |         -- move occurs because `wx` has type `Result<Arc<Watchexec>, CriticalError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
23 |     let main = wx.expect("REASON").mainf();
   |                -- ---------------- `wx` moved due to this method call
   |                |
   |                help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
...
26 |     wx.unwrap().config.pathset(["."]);
   |     ^^ value used here after move
   |
note: `Result::<T, E>::expect` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `wx`
  --> /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1024:19
help: you could `clone` the value and consume it, if the `CriticalError: Clone` trait bound could be satisfied
   |
23 |     let main = wx.clone().expect("REASON").mainf();
   |                  ++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `w-hdom` (bin "w-hdom") due to 1 previous error
dewachen@monordi:~/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom$ cargo build --all-features
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
   Compiling w-hdom v0.1.0 (/home/dewachen/eclipse-workspace/w-hdom)
error[E0599]: no method named `expect` found for struct `Arc<Watchexec>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:23:16
   |
23 |     let main = wx.expect("REASON").mainf();
   |                   ^^^^^^ method not found in `Arc<Watchexec>`

error[E0599]: no method named `unwrap` found for struct `Arc<Watchexec>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 |     wx.unwrap().config.pathset(["."]);
   |        ^^^^^^ method not found in `Arc<Watchexec>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `CriticalError: Diagnostic` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:4
   |
20 |     })?;
   |       ^ the trait `Diagnostic` is not implemented for `CriticalError`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Diagnostic`:
             MietteError
             InstallError
             MietteDiagnostic
   = note: required for `ErrReport` to implement `From<CriticalError>`
   = note: required for `Result<(), ErrReport>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, CriticalError>>`

warning: unused import: `IntoDiagnostic`
 --> src/main.rs:1:14
  |
1 | use miette::{IntoDiagnostic, Result};
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `w-hdom` (bin "w-hdom") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `w-hdom` (bin "w-hdom") due to 3 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

Comment: The error complains about *"use of moved value: `wcs`"*, but there is no `wcs` in your code example, please [edit] your post so the error is produced by the example you show.

Comment: Also have you tried what the compiler suggests, add `as_ref()` / `as_mut()` call just before `.unwrap()` / `.expect()`: `wx.as_ref().expect("").mainf()`

Comment: Also the [example you seem to be referencing](https://github.com/watchexec/watchexec/blob/a50ce396cb6b13b61badc722ca2ddee821ff87e8/crates/lib/examples/only_events.rs) is considerably different.

Answer (score 0):

i went to try the as_ref() field before unwrap() and before expect("")

and it has compile correctly, thanks

i'm new in rust, and it is completely different from python!